# swift: changing dictionary values in an array that holds multiple maps

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do the following but seems to be not acceptable operation. Perhaps I am missing something fundamental in the language.

```
var foo:NSArray = []
var bar = ["name":"jake"]
foo = [bar]
foo[0]["name"] = "Fred"
```

The last line throws an error saying  `'@lvalue $T8' is not identical to 'AnyObject!'` Is this sort of thing not allowed in swift? If so how do one go about achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to declare foo the right way. As an Array of Dictionaries:

```
var foo:[[String:AnyObject]] = []
var bar = ["name":"jake"]
foo = [bar]
foo[0]["name"] = "Fred"

foo   // [["name": "Fred"]]
```

Comment: perfect! did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Good to know about `String:AnyObject`. is this same as `NSMutableArray`? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: this is Swift as long as you declare it as a variable using "var" yes.

Comment: Take a look at nsuserdefaults how it stores dictionaires

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481299/ios-locally-saving-an-array-of-key-value-pairs/28482136#28482136

Comment: You are welcome. You should also tale a look at this answer's link above

Answer (score 0):

When you dereference with `foo[0]` the return type is `AnyObject`.  The type `AnyObject` does not have a `subscript` operator.  Use

```
(foo[0] as! [String:String])["name"]
```

Or, if your array will only hold dictionaries, then define it with:

```
var foo : [[String:String]] = []
```

Here is an example:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.
  1> var foo : [[String:String]] = [] 
foo: [[String : String]] = 0 values
  2> var bar : [String:String] = ["name":"jake"] 
  3.  
bar: [String : String] = {
  [0] = {
    key = "name"
    value = "jake"
  }
}
  3> foo = [bar] 
  4> foo[0]["name"] 
$R0: String? = "jake"
```